# BlueStacks emulator for Linux?

Tags: android, opengl-es, virtual-machine

I'm under linux and I need a VM running Android with OpenGL ES support, I know that [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) runs well under Windows and Mac, I'm wondering if there is a similar solution for Linux.

Thanks.

PS

I'm under Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit

Comment: IMHO the question was if there is some similar software runnning android or emulating it directly on Linux, not on Windows. Neither in VBox or native Windwos. Does someone know about those stacks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Genymotion runs with VBox/ Linux :) http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2333452

Comment: Really good emulator. Quite fast. I use it for WhatsApp.

Comment: i dont find an `app store` icon in the emulator @KazimZaidi can u put some light on this

Comment: I can't say exactly, but for me its right there in the top left corner when you open that grid menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is Android-x86 which can be installed in Virtual Box which has hardware acceleration. I am unsure though how well it will mirror a regular Android and how it relates to OpenGL ES.

Comment: it relates horribly, I already know that :(

Comment: Performance-wise or how it translates OpenGL ES? AndroVM seems to be used by some to play games.